# How do I get into the arena fight?

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

In Assassins Creed Origins how do I get into the arena fight?  Is it unlocked after a certain part of the story?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, full disclosure, I do not own nor have played AC:O.

However, after a quick search, it seems like [this guide](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/unlock-krokodilopolis-arena-assassins-creed-origins/) may be what you are looking for if you are looking to unlock the Krokodilopolis arena. Additionally, here is an excerpt from a [second page](http://www.gosunoob.com/assassins-creed-origins/how-to-unlock-gladiators-arena/) that corroborates the first guide, and both indicate that a story mission takes you to Krokodilopolis (emphasis mine).

> Krokodilopolis Gladiator Arena is found in the Faiyum Oasis (level 28-31 zone), in the southern part of the map. **To unlock this arena, you’ll need to complete a side quest called The Champion first**. This quest can be found in the northwestern part of Krokodilopolis, and it’ll task you with helping an aging gladiator. **There is also a level 28 main story quest called The Crocodile’s Jaws that takes you straight into this arena. Completing this one might also be a requirement for entering the arena.**

Here is an image of the location of The Champion sidequest which unlocks the arena.

[image: The Champion sidequest location]

Unlocking the second arena in Cyrene appears to be tied to completing challenges in the first as well as another related sidequest.